# Hide screen in Drawer Navigation - React Native

Tags: react-native, navigation, hide, drawer

So I'm trying to remove a item from the Navigation Drawer, it's OK if its there but not showing, nor should it be clickable.

```
<Drawer.Screen name="DetailsScreen" component={DetailsScreen} 
          options={{
            drawerLabel: () => null,
            title: null,
          }}/>
```

This code i have above works to a certain point, because i would like it to be NON clickable and also remove the highlight of it when people access the menu from detailscreen if that makes any sense. Any help is appreciated..

Note that all my screens are in the app.js file so i do not have any other components.

Answer (score 0):

if you have some props, you can make a condition... like:

```
{state.props == 'something-true' ?
(<Drawer.Screen name="DetailsScreen" component={DetailsScreen} 
      options={{
        drawerLabel: () => null,
        title: null,
      }}/>) :
null}
```

Comment: I can't set any style to it right away to make it go away? :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make Custom Drawer and then place condition for hidden tabs like this.

```
let hiddenTabs =[] <- from redux; // so you can change dynamically
navigation.state.routes.map((route, index) => {
    const focused = activeItemKey === route.key;
    const scene = { route, index, focused };
    const label = getLabel(scene);
    return (
        !hiddenTabs.includes(label) &&
        <TouchableOpacity key={index.toString()} onPress={() => navigation.navigate(label)}>
          <Text>{label}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
})
```

Don't need to hide screen in Router. As you can active these screen changing hiddenTabs list.

Comment: Could you please break that down a bit? I'm new to React-Native so sadly that does not make to much sense to me

Comment: A bit of explanation for the OP to understand would be great!

Answer (score 0):

In the options attribute, try `drawerItemStyle: { display: "none" }`.